# Positioning circle in table cell using one div

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css and have an interesting problem. I want to position a red circle of height and width 40px within a table cell, and maintain this height and width no matter what the table cell height or width. So it would look as follows:

[image]

With the circle always centered and the same size and the rest of the cell as whitespace. I also want to do this, if possible, using just one css class like below:

```
   td.circle {
        background: #f00;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        right:50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        transform: translate (50%,50%);
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

At the moment, the code I have expands the circles with and height with the width or height of the cell, is there a way to stop this happening?

Comment: I updated my answer with a second sample in the way you want, ... but I still recommend using `attr()` with `<td class="circle" data-char="H"></td>`, it is better, cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't put a div in the `td` and use that as your circle then it sounds like a job for a pseudo-element.

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
td.circle:before {
  content: attr(data-char);
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="circle" data-char="H"></td>
    <td class="circle" data-char="I"></td>
    <td class="circle" data-char="J"></td>
    <td class="circle" data-char="K"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**2nd Solution**

Can't honestly say I prefer this over an *actual* background image **but** if it has to be pure CSS and we aren't allowed any elements inside the `td` we can use a restricted circular radial gradient.

```css
.circle {
  background-image:
    -webkit-radial-gradient(
      circle,
      red, red 20px, transparent 20px
    );
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(
      circle,
      red, red 20px, transparent 20px
    );
border:1px solid grey;
}

table {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="circle">1</td>
    <td class="circle">2</td>
    <td class="circle">3</td>
    <td class="circle">4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. One last request - would it be easy to add text to the centre of this circle? For example "A". How could I go about this?

Comment: Is there a way to centre the text in the cell in the centre of the circle?

Comment: But for example the 'H' character between the td tags <td class="circle">H</td>

Comment: That's great, we are almost there. I want to use the 'H' character that was inserted in the middle of my td tag (<td class="circle">H</td>) rather than have the character in css. Is this possible?

Comment: Like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/2L4jcxo6/1/

 but with "H", "I", "J" and "K" centered within the circles. Is this possible without another div tag?

Comment: @MattMcGrath You can do it like this with Paulie's solution: https://jsfiddle.net/2L4jcxo6/2/

Comment: Thanks @LGSon, is there any way to use the text within the td tag for the centre of the circle? I need to to come from there

Comment: @MattMcGrath Yes, I updated Paulie's answer to show how.

Comment: @Paulie_D Updated some of your code, hope it was okay :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Paulie_D and LGSon. I see how this works but is there absolutely no way I can use the H within these two td tags like so: <td class="circle">H</td> ?

Comment: Figured out a way..but it's not my recommended solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with a div.

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25%;
  height: 80px;
}
.circle {
  content: "";
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle">H</div></td>
    <td><div class="circle">I</div></td>
    <td><div class="circle">J</div></td>
    <td><div class="circle">K</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update based on a comment.

Here is an alternative to Paulie's pseudo, using `position: absolute`, though I still recommend using `<td class="circle" data-char="H"></td>` instead. It gives better control as the letter is inside the pseudo, not outside as this one need to be.

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle:before {
  content: "";
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="circle">H</td>
    <td class="circle">I</td>
    <td class="circle">J</td>
    <td class="circle">K</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```